# C++ How do we make our application start on computer startup (and of course, after a user signed in)?

Tags: c++, windows-8, startup

How do we make our application start on computer startup (and of course, after the user had signed in)?
And no, I am not making a virus.

Does registry editing sound like a good idea?

My OS is Windows 8.

However, I will try to make my application available for all possible Window OS.

Comment: Services can be made to start running on start-up.

Comment: Do you want to specify an operating system?

Comment: I'd probably say the run part of the HKCU if you're on Windows. No need to invade their startup folder.

Comment: You need to specify an OS - the answer differs between them

Comment: @Robert you will get downvotes if you don;t provide basic information related to the question (like OS in this case) because it shows you did not do any research before asking the question.

Comment: @RobertWish Though I cannot answer you for sure, there is a plurality of possible reasons. First, you wrote it all too quickly, making lot of space for questions. Then your question is very broad. And would be even if OS was specified.

Comment: I guess those are some reasonable reasons. At least you guys gave a reason. I am a newbie here. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I think users should be **pushed** to explain downvotes. Myself, I found out that I never need to downvote, because I can always comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to do this is simply to add a shortcut to your application's executable to the user's Startup folder. You do not need to (and should not) modify the registry.

Advanced users know how to do this manually already, but it may also be an option you want to provide as part of your installer and/or a configuration dialog in your application.

To do this from C++ code, you will need to do two things:

1. **Retrieve the location of the current user's Startup folder.**

   This is accomplished by calling the [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) function and specifying the [`KNOWNFOLDERID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457.aspx) of the folder you're interested in. In this case, that would be `FOLDERID_Startup`.

   Sample code:

   ```
   std::wstring GetStartupFolderPath()
   {
       PWSTR pszPath;
       HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(&FOLDERID_Startup,
                                         0,     // no special options required
                                         NULL,  // no access token required
                                         &pszPath);
       if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
       {
           // The function succeeded, so copy the returned path to a
           // C++ string, free the memory allocated by the function,
           // and return the path string.
           std::wstring path(pszPath);
           CoTaskMemFree(static_cast<LPVOID>(pszPath));
           return path;
       }
       else
       {
           // The function failed, so handle the error.
           // ...
           // You might want to throw an exception, or just return an
           // empty string here.
           throw std::runtime_error("The SHGetKnownFolderPath function failed");
       }                            
   }
   ```

   Note, however, that while `SHGetKnownFolderPath` is the recommended function to use, it is supported only by Windows Vista and later. If you need to support older versions of the operating system, you'll need to call it dynamically on newer versions where it is available, and otherwise fall back to calling the [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx) function. This one takes a different type of identifier, a [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494.aspx) value. The one you want is `CSIDL_STARTUP`.
2. **Create a shortcut to your application's executable.**

   This is accomplished using a different set of Shell API functions. I won't bother writing up sample code here because it's all quite well explained on MSDN already: [Shell Links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891.aspx)

   Now you just connect the dots: when you create the shortcut to your application's executable, specify the user's Startup folder as its destination path.

The only other thing to be aware of is that there are actually multiple Startup folders. Each user has one, which is the one we retrieved above using `FOLDERID_Startup`. About 99% of the time, that's the one you want. Putting a shortcut to your app there will cause it to be launched automatically when that user logs on.

However, there is also a *global* Startup folder that is shared by all users. This one is identified by `FOLDERID_CommonStartup` (or `CSIDL_COMMON_STARTUP`) and requires administrative privileges to add items to. That makes sense, of course, because whatever you put in there is going to launch automatically when *any* user logs on to the computer. Only administrators can affect global behavior like this. And chances are, your app doesn't need this anyway.

Comment: "Dynamic calling" is not necessary. If you target XP and later (i.e. you compile to `NTDDI_WINXP`), call `SHGetFolderPath`. If you target Vista and/or later (`>=NTDDI_VISTA`), call `SHGetKnownFolderPath`. Such dynamic behavior is only rarely needed, when a new function is useful but not required.

Comment: It's not strictly necessary, no, but I personally prefer to use the recommended APIs where possible. The older `SHGetFolderPath` function is still supported for the present time in Windows 7 and 8, but it is liable to go away at any time. If you're already using the current API, you'll have a much easier time targeting your code for a newer version of Windows. Besides, there are often features of the newer API that don't exist for the older one. I wrap all of this up in a library.

Comment: You're probably missing the point. There are many more XP features that might go away in Windows 9. It doesn't really help to create a complex solution around one feature, and then have another XP dependency elsewhere. So, even if you target Windows, you should still set a minimum version. Besides, that function really isn't going away. It's deprecated because it's clumsy. Just look at `OpenFile`, which has been deprecated since NT4 or so.

Answer (score 3):

#### Start menu

Simplest solution is to place `.lnk` of `.bat` file into the `Start Menu\On startup` folder. This is easiest and not too sneaky against the user.

#### Registry:

Another solution is creating the key in the registry keys:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]   //All users
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]  //All users once 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]  //Currend user
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce] //Current user once
```

This is not that transparent - so a bit more agressive against the user.

Comment: Thank you @Tomáš Zato. I will accept this answer in 8 minute.

Comment: This deppends on the configuration, but upon the same level of configuretion, the same permissions will be required. So unless you are going to exploit the system, it does not matter what you choose.

Comment: That's not correct. Elevation will be required to add a program to the Startup Items folder for All Users

Comment: *"That's not correct."* Do you mean that **no** elevation is required to alter the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`? Or the current users Startup folder?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Users have permission to modify the files in their own Startup folder because those affect only their account. And since the user has the requisite permissions, all applications that they're running have those same permissions. Elevation is required to do things that will affect other users or the entire system.

Comment: So, Tomas is right. At the same level (Startup menu for All Users, HKLM) you need the same permissions (Administrator, UAC elevation).

Answer (score 1):

On windows you can put a shortcut to your application in the `Startup` folder, or you can implement it as a service.

And that "I am not making a virus" does make you sound guilty... Maybe it is a keylogger? ;)

Comment: Its not a keylogger and its not a virus. xD

Comment: Its true that saying *"I'm making a ... program."* would sound much more reliable.

Comment: Haha, its a messenger - that doesn't send any PC info or what the user did.

Comment: @RobertWish you just make it sound more and more suspicious ;) There is a saying in my language, which translates to something like: "Guilty consciousness runs without being chased" - I think that by default people assume you are not making a harmful program, so there is no need to deny it without being confronted in the first place.

Comment: In my homeland, we say something like *"Shot goose honks first."*. Decades old, still true :)

Comment: Lmao, don't worry about it guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways, but they all depend on your OS. For windows take a look at the "Task Schedualer" under "Administrative tools" in the control panel.

Comment: Task shleduling is evil and non transparent. At least it seemed so to me.

Comment: "Depend on your OS". Good point, that means I need to detect the user's OS..does anyone have any idea how I would do that?

Comment: I find it much less evil than editing the registry or injecting lines in a startup file. the real evil is that there are so many ways for somone to launch code at startup, rather than a single unified place.

Comment: @Robert generally you will have some idea when you compile, or else your program will be unable to load.

Comment: @tletnes Better yet, I should just supply different version. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: There is nothing "evil" about scheduled tasks. It's just not the correct way to launch an application at startup. It serves a very different purpose.

Comment: so then what are the "when the computer starts" and "when I log on" triggers for then?

Comment: There is no "when the computer starts" trigger. The "when I log on" trigger is the Startup folder.

Comment: @Cody which version of windows are you using? Are you andministrator? On Win7 with an Admin account I have a "when the computer starts" trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Note, this code snippet is not written by me.

```
#include <windows.h>

void Reg() {
    ::HKEY Handle_Key = 0;
    ::DWORD Dispoition = 0;

    ::RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                    "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
                    0,
                    KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
                    &Handle_Key );
    const unsigned char Path[ MAX_PATH ] = "C:\\Windows\\YourProgramName.exe";
    ::RegSetValueEx( Handle_Key, "My Directory", 0, 1, Path, sizeof( unsigned char ) );
};
```

What do you guys think?

Comment: At least share with us, which libraries are included.

Comment: Who wrote it? You should attribute it to them, perhaps by linking to the original. Beyond that, I see two other problems. 1) There's no reason to edit the registry. Adding a shortcut to the Startup folder is sufficient and is the preferred approach. 2) This code writes to HKLM, which affects *all* users. Chances are, that's not what you want. Use HKCU instead to affect only the current user account.